# setAlpha() on onBindView in RecyclerView doesn't work on first display

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Using the following code within a RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position){
   holder.itemView.setAlpha(0.5f);
}
```

Alpha will not be shown the first time the item is shown. However, if you leave the screen and come back, Alpha is then accurately shown. The value is being set, but not displayed until it's shown again. Any ideas on how to get setAlpha() to take effect on first viewing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After further investigation, this happens only when using an animator (such as the android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator ) which will clear whatever alpha is set for the view. You can use

`RecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);`

and alpha will remain set

Comment: This does not really solve the problem if you DO need item inimator

Answer (score 16):

The `RecyclerView` default animator modifies the alpha set on the `itemView` set on the `ViewHolder`.

Wrap your `itemView` layout in a `FrameLayout` and modify the alpha of the children of the `FrameLayoyt` e.g:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/system_modifies_my_alpha">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_holder_bind_modifies_my_alpha">
        <!-- your children go here-->
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to set [setAlpha()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)) during the  creation of the Holder,

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
...
...
    public ViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);
        ...
        ...
        itemView.setAlpha(0.5f);
    }
}
```

not only inside `onBindViewHolder()`

```
onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position){
   holder.itemView.setAlpha(0.5f);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)
Alpha is actually a float value between 0 and 1